# Dockerfile example with VS2019 build

Tags: docker, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

Is there any example dockerfile which can be used for building vs2019 written code, I have dependency with 2019 version , because I am trying to build a database project. I have installed visualstudio2019buildtools from chocolatey and my container running , but msbuild is still not recognized.

Comment: Maybe you could get some help from [this document](https://blog.alexellis.io/3-steps-to-msbuild-with-docker/)..

Comment: What do you mean msbuild is still not recognized?